# Treesitter produces error nodes even though other match seems possible

Tags: treesitter

I am trying to parse a language with identifiers and also literals.

```
b
b""
```

Here `b` is an indentifier, and `b""` is a literal (also possible would be e.g., `b"foo"`).

I have the following simplified grammar:

```
module.exports = grammar({
    name: 'foo',

    rules: {
        file: $ => repeat(choice(
            $.ident,
            $.literal,
        )),

        ident: _ => /[a-z]/,
        literal: _ => seq('b', /\"[a-z]*\"/),
    },
});
```

This produces the following match state:

```
(file [0, 0] - [2, 0]
  (ERROR [0, 0] - [0, 1])
  (literal [1, 0] - [1, 3]))
foo.bar 0 ms    (ERROR [0, 0] - [0, 1])
```

I.e., I am able to parse constructs like `b""`, but the matcher for `ident` goes on an error branch and does not recover.

I have experimented with `token` without success. What is missing here?

Comment: I have found the GH discussions for tree-sitter and also [asked this question there](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter/discussions/857). Will report back should I get an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @maxbrunsfeld in the GH discussions, `token` is indeed the answer for this toy example.

With the following change this toy example does indeed work:

```
-         literal: _ => seq('b', /\"[a-z]*\"/),
+         literal: _ => token(seq('b', /\"[a-z]*\"/)),
```

```
(file [0, 0] - [2, 0]
  (ident [0, 0] - [0, 1])
  (literal [1, 0] - [1, 3]))
```

If the matcher for the quoted part of `literal` becomes more complicated, this like expected runs into the usual issues around non-terminals, but this is a feature of `token`, not the example I posted, e.g.,

```js
        ident: _ => /[a-z]/,
        literal: $ => token(seq('b', $.ident)), // WRONG.
```

```
Error processing rule literal
Details:
  Grammar error: Unexpected rule Symbol(Symbol { kind: NonTerminal, index: 1 })
```